# Getting a comma inserted between fields when exporting data using out-file Powershell

Tags: powershell, export, export-to-csv

When I export the two fields they show up underneath each other instead of side by side.  I tried export-csv and only get he the field size values instead of the data.  Please advise.

```
$computername = (Get-item env:COMPUTERNAME).value
$One_Drive_Version = (Get-Item $env:userprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe).VersionInfo.FileVersion
$computername, $One_Drive_Version | Out-File "//SERVER/OneDriveVersion/onedriveVersion.csv" -force -append
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either concatenate them manually:

```
$output = "$computername,$One_Drive_Version" | Out-File ...
# or 
$output = $computername,$One_Drive_Version -join ',' | Out-File ...
# then
```

or create an object and pipe that to `Export-Csv`:

```
[pscustomobject]@{
    ComputerName = $computername
    Version      = $One_Drive_Version
} |Export-Csv "//SERVER/OneDriveVersion/onedriveVersion.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

```
($computername + "," + $One_Drive_Version) | Out-File //SERVER/OneDriveVersion/onedriveVersion.csv" -force -append
```

There you go